How to upload Crestron Construct and SIMPLE#/C#/HTML5 to a Crestron touchpanel and processor. Also How to use a .cs file in SIMPLE# or C#
I need some help with Crestron Construct and SIMPLE#/C#/HTML5. I also want to know how to use a .cs file in SIMPLE# or C#.
Here is the exactly what I help with:

Crestron Construct creating Chd files
Creating Chd file from HTML5
The use of .cs files in SIMPLE# or C#
How to upload Crestron Construct compiled file /HTML5 file to a touch panel (TSW-1070).
How to upload a C#/SIMPL# file to processor.

Any help will be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.
BTW, I don't have much experience with Crestron. I have contacted Crestron for help, but they have been useless so far. I have tried Reddit, GitHub and other forums to try and find a solution, but I have had no luck in finding a solution.
